# how to make rails `LIKE` more flexible?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I've got a little issue with my LIKE query.

I have this this query here

```
gmiurldb = Gmi.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND delivery_time = ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{tmname}%", "#{tmtime}", "#{tmdate}").first
```

Now the `ILIKE` isn't flexible enough for what i need. For example.

I'm trying to search `John Cooper Clark`

and that matches fine

However `Dr John Cooper Clark` doesn't match to anything. Even though `John Cooper Clark` does exist. Any ideas why this doesn't work? and how i can make it work?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: This is not about Rails. It's about SQL.

Comment: Did not finish my comment:-( This is not about Rails but SQL, i assume. What is the expected behavior of the search?

Depending on your data and requirements you can do various things: 

* split by whitespace, make an ORed query
* use one of the search plugins available for AR (depending on your DB)
* use an external search index

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`full text search`](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/), which is *kind-of* what you're doing.

I don't have massive db experience, although we have made something similar:

[image]

To get the above working (it only works for full words), we had to use the following:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(search)
     if Rails.env.production? #PGSQL
       basic_search(name: search, description: search).take(5)
     else #MYSQL
       where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%",  "%#{search}%").take(5)
     end
  end
end
```

The `basic_search` method came from the [`Textacular`](https://github.com/textacular/textacular) gem (for PGSQL)

---

As per the comments, the question is not Ruby but SQL, and it's many flavours.

It looks like you're doing the right thing; the only problem I would say is that if you're using `ILIKE` (IE you're using `PGSQL`), you'd probably be better using the `textacular` to perform the search.

Apart from that, I don't have anything else; I'll delete the answer if off-topic etc.